# Quokka not running in VSCode, showing long string of Javascript

Tags: javascript, quokka.js

I am taking a React class on Udemy and one of the sections is a refresher on Javascript.  This module uses Quokka to run the code.  When I attempt to run Quokka by using Start on Current File, it doesn't run and in the output window that shows up, it displays a long string of Javascript.  I didn't find anything online and nobody on Udemy has seen this before.  I am using a 2021 MBP.

I am using Node.js v21.4.0,

Here is what it looks like.

[image: Quokka in VSCode]

I did add the path to Node.js in the config file, even though it is in my path, and it made no difference.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Quokka multiple times.  I tried a bunch of older versions of Quokka.

Comment: I'm reading quokka.js getting started instructions [here](https://quokkajs.com/docs/#getting-started) and you don't seem to be doing any of that

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded from Node.js v21.4.0 to v20.10.0 and it now works fine.